# Why is length of array still same after realloc?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

This is part of my code :

```
array = (int *) malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

it is initialised and has some values, I am skipping this step here for more clearance.

```
memmove(array, array + 1, 4*sizeof(int));
array = realloc(array, 4*sizeof(int));
```

What i wanted to accomplish here is to remove first member of array and to move whole array one step to the left. Still when I try to check length of array using :

```
strlen(array);
```

I get value 5. It seems like realloc doesn't work properly, because when I also try to print fifth element of an array, which should be after realloc out of arrays range, it prints value which i previously gave to it. How is it possible?

Can somebody point me out where am I making mistake and what am I missing?

Comment: 1) A pointer is not an array. 2) C does not have a distinct string type. 3) What does your C book say about `strlen` and C strings in general? What did your find by a simple search?

Comment: Why are you applying `strlen` to what appears to be an array of `int`s? What do you expect `strlen` to do in this case? And what did the compiler tell you about your `strlen(array)` expression?

Answer (score 3):

`strlen` computes the length of a NUL-terminated string. It is 5 by luck (encounters a zero at some point): undefined behaviour.

And it's a size in *bytes*. The size of your array is `5*sizeof(int)` so probably 20 or 40 depending on the actual size of `int`. Not what you're looking for anyway.

There's no way of telling the "length" of an block allocated by `malloc` or `realloc` (aside from storing it!)

(but your `realloc` operation is valid)

note: variations of this mistake would be to rely on `sizeof(array)` which is the size of the pointer type because `array` is a pointer, not an array!